# Selecting multiple values from 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select multiple values from 2 columns.  I can get the query working with 1 column, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    town IN ( 'Oxford' , 'Abingdon' )
```

However, I want to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    town IN ( 'Oxford' , 'Abingdon' )
AND type IN ( 'type1','type2')
```

but I can't get it to work.

Basically I want to select all where:

- town=Oxford and type=type1
- town=Oxford and type=type2
- town=Abingdon and type=type1
- town=Abingdon and type=type2

Comment: Second query looks good to me... unless I am totally missing something.

Comment: your something like query look that is good , did you try to run it?

Comment: "but I can't get it to work." - Do you get an error? Does it return no results? Is the data actually there for the scenarios you mention (i.e. are all Oxford and Abingdon records actually type3 and type 4)?

Comment: What exactly error do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE  (town IN ( 'Oxford' , 'Abingdon' )) AND (type IN ( 'type1','type2'))
```

Comment: Well, It must be a bad day! I must have had a typo AND was stupid enough not to check the error messages before posting! You're all right - The query I typed into my message works - DOH!